# Looping multiple scanner inputs until a specific input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input, variable-assignment

I am new to java, and I am doing this assignment for a romanCalculator.
I am currently doing with the calculation part but i am having an issue with some of the rules requested.

**If the input is incorrect, an error has to be printed.**

So this is one of the rules, and these are the only possible inputs.

```
<possible Roman number> <operator> <possible Roman number>
```

OR

```
<possible Roman number> <operator> <possible Roman number>
```

OR

```
.
```

The first 2 are easy to understand, and the . is to exit the program.

This is all what i could do with my knowledge:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String firstRoman = in.next();
    String operator = in.next();
    String secondRoman = in.next();
```

It just asks once and only 1 form of input.
I can't figure out how to apply this to what is requested, I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
\begin{ipoutput} XX \end{ipoutput}
\begin{ipinput} *xii

\begin{ipinput} /vi \end{ipinput}
\begin{ipoutput} XL

\begin{ipoutput} MCDXLV \end{ipoutput}
\begin{ipinput} .
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    System.out.println("Enter your roman numbers\nEx: X + V\n:");
    while(!(input = in.nextLine()).equals("."))
    {
        //assuming splitting the input around whitespace we can do the following
        String[] userInput = input.split("\\s+");
        if(userInput.length == 3)
        {
            String firstRoman = userInput[0];
            String operator = userInput[1];
            String secondRoman = userInput[2];
            if(firstRoman.matches("[MCDXLV]+") && operator.matches("\\+|\\-") && secondRoman.matches("[MCDXLV]+"))
            {
                //we have some valid things to work with let's continue
                System.out.println("Valid input - " + input);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid input - " + input);
            }
            //do your thing
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input - " + input);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter your roman numbers\nEx: X + V\n:");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but I wrote the wrong second possible option. it should be like this

Comment: Like the example, it would work with the last answer i got from the previous function.